# how to use any external library in JavaScript from the browser ? (without preprocessing)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I want to use this library in the browser:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-goat

and say I cannot do any pre-processing 
(for all it matters the script is loaded dynamically because users can choose any script)

If I load it from the browser I get

**Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined**

that makes sense because there is code like this:

```
exports.escape = ... 
exports.unescape = ...
```

I can solve this issue by doing the following:

```
<script>exports = {};</script>
<script src='...'></script>
```

But is that correct ?
what's the general solution to fix this problem ? 
is there a polyfill for exports being undefined ?
Am I missing something ?

thanks

Comment: It's a node.js package and doesn't run in a browser

Comment: Your fix may work for one library, but the export variable is a keyword that can appear in any or all files in a library. It is used to expose the contents of a file.

Comment: @holger fair point. Some libraries won't work on the browser but many will. (the one I provided would work for example... so my question remains what's the best solution to tackle this)

Comment: @Pineda thanks. I am after the cleanest approach. I appreciate not all JS files can be ran on the browser

Comment: Why don't you want to preprocess?

Comment: This is CommonJS module, and it is supposed to be preprocessed when being used in browser. You can fork it and convert to UMD module. Or process it dynamically with SystemJS. Honestly, 'I don't want to do any preprocessing !!!' doesn't sound like a very good argument.

Comment: saying "i don't want to preprocess in a modern js app" is like saying "i don't want to compile my C programs before executing them" – don't get me wrong, the JS module scene is a nightmare right now, but that's just the reality of things until [something more concrete/established](http://2ality.com/2017/05/es-module-specifiers.html) comes along

Comment: @naomik fair enough. I will edit my question.

Comment: Have you tried browserify? You can use ajax to fetch script and evaluate it once its loaded.

Comment: can I use browserify from the browser ?